# How to calculate the traveled distance in here map

Tags: android, here-api

I want to calculate the traveled distance over a navigation in here map . The calculation get some error distance when re-routing happened

i have tried the getElapsedDistance from the navigation manager but it goes to zero when there is a re-route happened

the code i tried is m_navigationManager.getElapsedDistance();

I expect the output of 19000 meter, but the actual output is 16500

Answer (score 0):

I calculate the distance between two positions like

```
startGeoPosition.distanceTo(endGeoPosition)
```

It is working fine for me, please try it.